# where does RPM install custom GPG keys?

Tags: centos6, rpm, keys

Where does CentOS/RHEL 6 store custom GPG keys? I thought /etc/pki/rpm-gpg but I installed nginx's key but unable to find it. I see it was imported properly but where is it?

```
wget http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key
rpm --import nginx_signing.key

[root@web1-ftl rpm-gpg]# rpm -qi gpg-pubkey-7bd9bf62-4e4e3262
Name        : gpg-pubkey                   Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 7bd9bf62                          Vendor: (none)
Release     : 4e4e3262                      Build Date: Wed 05 Feb 2014 03:26:35 AM UTC
Install Date: Wed 05 Feb 2014 03:26:35 AM UTC      Build Host: localhost
Group       : Public Keys                   Source RPM: (none)
Size        : 0                                License: pubkey
Signature   : (none)
Summary     : gpg(nginx signing key <signing-key@nginx.com>)
Description :
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: rpm-4.8.0 (NSS-3)
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=A015
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Comment: question similar to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28479/when-importing-a-key-during-a-yum-installation-where-is-that-key-stored

Answer (score 9):

They are stored in the RPM database, which is in */var/lib/rpm*. From the
manpage

```
Digital signatures cannot be verified without a public key.  An ASCII 
armored public  key  can  be added  to  the rpm database using --import. An 
imported public key is carried in a header, and keyring management is 
performed exactly like package management. For example, all currently  
imported public keys can be displayed by:

rpm -qa gpg-pubkey*

Details about a specific public key, when imported, can be displayed by 
querying.  Here’s information about the Red Hat GPG/DSA key:

rpm -qi gpg-pubkey-db42a60e

Finally, public keys can be erased after importing just like packages. 
Here’s how  to  remove  the Red Hat GPG/DSA key

rpm -e gpg-pubkey-db42a60e
```

*/etc/pki/rpm-gpg* is the standard place for packages with repository
configuration (like [epel-release](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/epel-release.html)) to put keys they want to be imported.
The yum configuration in the package will have the path to the key in the
*gpgkey* directive. The first time you try to install a package from a
repository yum prompts you to import the key.