# How to reposync saltstack? reposync failing with error message `Removing [...], due to missing GPG key.`

Tags: saltstack, gpg, reposync

On a RHEL 7.4 system, I add the salt-latest repo as follows:

```
yum -y install https://repo.saltstack.com/yum/redhat/salt-repo-latest-2.el7.noarch.rpm
```

Notice, amongst other things, this creates the following two GPG key files:

```
/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7-Salt
/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/saltstack-signing-key
```

For later reference, notice the fingerprint of the CentOS key ends with f4a80eb5:

```
# gpg --quiet --with-fingerprint /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7-Salt

pub  4096R/F4A80EB5 2014-06-23 CentOS-7 Key (CentOS 7 Official Signing Key) <security@centos.org>
      Key fingerprint = 6341 AB27 53D7 8A78 A7C2  7BB1 24C6 A8A7 F4A8 0EB5
```

Attempt to reposync download:

```
mkdir /root/foobar

reposync --gpgcheck --plugins --repoid=salt-latest --download_path=/root/foobar --newest-only --downloadcomps --delete --download-metadata
```

It fails with errors like these:

```
Removing babel-0.9.6-8.el7.noarch.rpm, due to missing GPG key.
Removing libyaml-0.1.4-11.el7_0.i686.rpm, due to missing GPG key.
Removing libyaml-0.1.4-11.el7_0.x86_64.rpm, due to missing GPG key.
```

So I manually download all the files that failed (in a for-loop) and check the signatures of their signing keys. They are all the same, so here's just one of them for example:

```
wget http://repo.saltstack.com/yum/redhat/7/x86_64/latest/base/babel-0.9.6-8.el7.noarch.rpm

rpm -K babel-0.9.6-8.el7.noarch.rpm

babel-0.9.6-8.el7.noarch.rpm: RSA sha1 ((MD5) PGP) md5 NOT OK (MISSING KEYS: (MD5) PGP#f4a80eb5)
```

Notice the key `PGP#f4a80eb5` matches the key referenced above, `F4A8 0EB5`. So why is it failing the gpg check?

Things I've tried include:

- I edited `/etc/yum.repos.d/salt-latest.repo` and changed the `gpgkey=` line. I got the same failure with all three of these variations. As far as I can tell, changing the `gpgkey=` line has no effect:

  ```
  gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/saltstack-signing-key
  gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7-Salt
  gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/saltstack-signing-key,file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7-Salt
  ```
- I tried running `reposync` without `--gpgcheck`. It works, but obviously, it's bad to use it this way.

  ```
  reposync --plugins --repoid=salt-latest --download_path=/root/foobar --newest-only --downloadcomps --delete --download-metadata
  ```
- I wonder if reposync is refusing to use the key because it's too weak? MD5. But I couldn't think of any way to confirm or deny this.
- I wonder if the key actually has an expiration date? But I couldn't find any way to confirm or deny this either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I stumbled upon the answer! It seems, `rpm` must keep a keystore someplace separate from `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg`, and it seems insufficient for the `gpgkey=` line to be specified in the repo file.

After doing this, `reposync` works, and correctly validates all the signatures of all the files:

```
rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7-Salt
```

Also see [where does rpm install custom gpg keys?](https://serverfault.com/questions/573249/where-does-rpm-install-custom-gpg-keys). Keys are stored in the rpm database, and can be queried and removed using the following commands:

```
List the installed keys
    rpm -qa gpg-pubkey*

Get info about a particular installed key
    rpm -qi gpg-pubkey-db42a60e

Remove a particular installed key
    rpm -e gpg-pubkey-db42a60e
```

Contrary to @sciurus's answer, this information is *not* in the man page (at least not in RHEL 7.4).